# How to parse SOAP XML-answer with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have XML-answer, as shown lower.

How to parse correctly this answer by php & SimpleXml?
Now I use 'str_replace" to remove strings, such as "soap:Envelope", "simplexml_load_string" and etc.
Are there more correct variants for parsing string on to get fields "code" and "message"?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <example:app_response xmlns:m="urn:QWERTY/YTREWQ/application">
      <code>0</code>
      <message/>
    </example:app_response>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: where do you get those xml answers? soap client function calls usually return at least std object

Comment: Sorry, but such here specific bus which returns such responses

Answer (score -1):

If you have this xml as string then I would get the code with `preg_match` call. With pattern like `<code>(.+)</code>`

Comment: I wouldn't. For a start, that particular regex would match `<code>foo</code><label>bar</label></message><message><code>bar</code>` all in one go, because `.+` will try to match as much as it can. That example is easily fixed, but if you use an XML parser every time, you won't have to worry about mistakes and annoying edge-cases like that. :)